# How can I undo the failed installation due to space limitation?

Tags: software-installation, disk-usage

Last week while I was installing the texlive-full in the Ubuntu system in VMWare I found that it took too much time, and then I went back home left it installing. But when I came back, something weird appeared:
1. Many Vim plugins yelled at me.
2. After rebooting, I got stuck with a totally black screen.
3. My Genome was gone. I can only interact with the OS via command line after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
4. Since I got to know that I need extend the disk space for the Virtual machine, I attempted to get it done by following [this awesome tutorial](http://www.joomlaworks.net/blog/item/168-resizing-the-disk-space-on-ubuntu-server-vms-running-on-vmware-esxi-5), but got stuck again when trying this command `pvcreate /dev/sda3`. The system told me that it had not been installed. But when I run `sudo apt-get install lvm2`, it reminded me that I should run `sudo apt-get -f install` with no parameters instead first.
5. But I saw that the failed texlive-full was being installing, and again it failed because of the limited space issue.
6. Then I deleted about 1.5G of files. I checked it by running `df -h` after `sudo apt-get clean`. But when I run the command I run in the 4th step, the error saying `E: Write error - Write (28: No space left on device) E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.` reoccured.

Then my question is that **what I can do to undo the interrupted installation of texlive-full**? It seems that it has not been automatically undoed after the failure. I don't want, and it seems that I need not, to delete more files for more space.

Comment: I would recommend booting from a live cd and extend your disk space first then update everything.

Comment: post (pastebin) the exact command you ran and the exact error message. I am guessing /boot or some specific partition is full

Comment: @bodhi.zazenSorry I cannot reproduce the prompts which guide me to run ```apt-get -f install```. All errors shown are the same as that one in the 6th step.

Comment: @DnrDevil I don't get you, could you please answer the question in detail? Or redirect me to some tutorials?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD "sudo apt-get  install gparted" http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to expand the ext4 primary partition size in a VMware Player virtual disk?](https://askubuntu.com/q/294889/)

Answer (score 0):

I have tackled the problem by four steps: 0) delete some files and complte the installation and then remove the software; 1) Set the VMware to extend the storage; 2) create a new filesystem and mount it to the root one; 3) install the latex by setting the installing directory.

```
#   TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX         /usr/local/texlive   => $tex_prefix
```

According the the above line in the `install_tl` file and the explanation in the [documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-260003.2.3) I get to know that I should change the value of the variable tex_prefix only.

Reference
http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html