# expanding VM with gparted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, virtualbox, gparted

I want to resize my Ubuntu VM, so I installed another Ubuntu installation (using VirtualBox) and ran Gparted on it. Here's a screenshot of the state of the partition: [image]

In `/dev/sda6`, I have 3GB of the 14.3GB that are already used. I believe this is related to the Ubuntu VM which I am currently in. My question is how can I expand the `/dev/sda1` in order to get 14.3Gb - 3Gb  more space ?

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/294889/how-to-expand-the-ext4-primary-partition-size-in-a-vmware-player-virtual-disk - you need to remove swap to grow /sda1. A much faster way would be to create a new VDI and just copy the files to there.

Comment: In order to move the space, the partitions must not be active.  You will need to boot from Live media containing GParted.  See [Moving Space Between Partitions](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions) and relevant Virtual Box [GParted - articles/tutorials](http://gparted.org/articles.php).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are having trouble with is a communication between Virtualbox, and your physical machine. When you load *any OS/VM* in Virtualbox you are asked to allocate a certain set space that it can use. What happens is that a "fake disk" is created, and that is what is used for the VM. In the current latest version of Ubuntu Virtualbox, I do not believe you can communicate physical data between partitions of Virtualbox -> Your hard-drive (or vice-versa)