# Low Disk Space on "Filesystem Root" in Ubuntu

Tags: filesystem, ram, vmware, disk-usage, disk

I keep getting this message (Low Disk Space on "Filesystem Root") every time I open Ubuntu. I run Ubuntu on VMware Workstation. I installed some packages for a simulator that I want to use for university... I installed the virtual machine with all its files in the local disk (D:) where I have more than 190 GB free space. Can someone explain what is the Filesystem root and how can I give it more space from my laptop? I installed some packages for a simulator that I want to use for university...

Comment: You would need to provide additional info here. It sounds like the virtual disk in VMWare isn't large enough. Since you write "Local disk (D:)", it would seem you run VMWare on Windows. Questions related to this should instead go to [su].

Comment: "in the local disk (D:) where I have more than 190 GB free space" That is windows free space, the notice is about the free space is INSIDE the VM,

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to expand the ext4 primary partition size in a VMware Player virtual disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294889/how-to-expand-the-ext4-primary-partition-size-in-a-vmware-player-virtual-disk)